# Call an external function from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Noob here, sorry in advance if this is a dumb question.

I am working with SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2.

I need to implement an inverse beta function within SQL.  (You pass in an alpha, beta and probability and the result is an x value.)  SQL doesn't have this function built in, so I need to either:

1. purchase an expensive math package that I won't make full use of, or
2. call an external program to do the calculation for me.

My question is: how do I do (B) ? Is it possible to call a function in R from SQL? Or maybe c# or PHP? I've googled a bit and i can't seem to find any good documentation on calling external functions.

Comment: Is the function really so complex that you can not write it in T-SQL ?

Comment: `median` isn't even built in to MS SQL ...but all those things can generally be coded. Excel is a pretty good app for calculations.

Comment: Yes, it would be pretty difficult to do in T-SQL. Generally, you would need Excel, R, Matlab, etc. for this type of math.

Excel would work as well.  Better, in fact.  I just don't know how to call external programs from within MSSQL.  I'm going to check out the documentation that paulsm4 linked to and see if that helps me.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't call a function in another language (like R) directly from MSSQL.

Yes, you *can* write some managed code that you can call from MSSQL, and which should, in turn, be able to call your R function.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

If you were to consider this, you *definitely* want to look at R.Net:

- http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/